# how to pass the file containing the file name as argument

Tags: shell-script, find

I have a file called **filelist.txt** where it contains a list of  file names. 
I need to search for these files by passing the **filelist.txt** as argument

Comment: So, what stops you from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this from bash would be:

```
cat filelist.txt | xargs find
```

xargs would build and execute a *find* command for every line of input passed to it. In this case a list of filenames.